# Capturing group inside non capturing group

Tags: java, regex

I'm currently struggling parsing a String which resembles a version.

My regex so far `v(\\d+)_(\\d+)(?:_(\\d+))?` which should match a String in the following format: **v*Version*_*InterimVersion*_*PatchVersion***. My aim is, that the last matching group (**_*PatchVersion***) is optional.

My problem is the optional part. A String `v1_00` will give me a `matcher.groupCount` of 3. I would have expected a groupCount of 2. So I guess either my regex is wrong or I'm having trouble understanding `matcher.groupCount`.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final String versionString = "v1_00";

    final String regex = "v(\\d+)_(\\d+)(?:_(\\d+))?";

    final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(apiVersionString);
    if (matcher.matches()) {

      final int version = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
      final int interimVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
      int patchVersion = 0;
      if (matcher.groupCount() == 3) {
        patchVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
      }
      // ...

    }
}
```

Comment: Non-capturing group is still a group, which is why it returns what it does. The `groupCount` is actually a state of `Pattern`, not `Matcher`, and mainly intended for use in things which use matcher like indexed collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are as many groups as there are capturing groups in the regex. If you have 3 sets of unescaped parentheses in  your pattern, there will be `matcher.group(1)`, `matcher.group(2)` and `matcher.group(3)`.

If Group 3 does not match, its value is *null*. Check Group 3 for the *null* value:

```
if (matcher.group(3) != null) {
    patchVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
}
```

See the [Java online demo](https://ideone.com/mbavCI):

```
final String versionString = "v1_00";
final String regex = "v(\\d+)_(\\d+)(?:_(\\d+))?";
final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(versionString);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    final int version = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    final int interimVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    int patchVersion = 0;
    if (matcher.group(3) != null) {
        patchVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
    }
    System.out.println(version + " > " + interimVersion  + " > " + patchVersion);
}
```

Results: `1 > 0 > 0`.

Comment: or a `Optional.ofNullable(matcher.group(3)).map(Integer::parseInt).orElse(0)` for a one-liner.